# ¿Cómo agregar más de una UIBarButtonItem a rightBarButtonItem en ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Estoy intentando poner más de un botón en la parte derecha de la `UINavigationBar` de [ios](/questions/tagged/ios)

El siguiente código muestra un botón a la izquierda y uno a la derecha, pero quiero añadirle el botón `*descargaButton` a la parte derecha. **¿Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?**

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"atras.png"] 
                                imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]
                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                target:self 
                                action:@selector(backAction)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                           initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"refrescar.png"]
                           imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]
                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                           target:self
                           action:@selector(refrescar)];

UIBarButtonItem *descargaButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                   initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"agenda.png"]
                                   imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] 
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                   target:self 
                                   action:@selector(descargarHorarioAction)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías usar la propiedad `rightBarButtonItems` (en plural) en lugar de `rightBarButtonItem` (en singular).

[Ver la documentación](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624956-rightbarbuttonitems) (en inglés).

Tu código quedaría así:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[button, descargaButton];
```

Comment: Muchas gracais por la respuesta voy a probarlo

Comment: Funciona perfectamente!!!